# Can't get ggraph to display labels for a dendrogram

Tags: r, label, data-science, dendrogram, ggraph

I use ggraph to visualise the results from a cluster analysis. But I can't get ggraph to display labels. I tried adding them as row names to the data, and I tried adding them as a vector to labels – to no avail. I'm very new to `ggraph`: Any help or criticism welcome.

MWE:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cluster)
library(ggraph)

mat <- matrix(rnorm(n = 25, mean = 6, sd = 2.7))
rownames(mat) <- sample(LETTERS, size = 25, replace = FALSE)
dend_labels <- rownames(mat)

mat %>% 
  dist(method = "euclidean") %>% 
  agnes(metric = "ward") %>% 
  as.hclust() %>% 
  as.phylo() %>% 
  ggraph(layout = "dendrogram") +
  geom_edge_elbow() + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = dend_labels))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```r
mat %>% 
  dist(method = "euclidean") %>% 
  agnes(metric = "ward") %>% 
  as.hclust() %>% 
  as.phylo() %>% 
  ggraph(layout = "dendrogram") +
  geom_edge_elbow() + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name, filter = leaf)) +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

Comment: label = name inside aes() did the trick! Thank you so much Allan.